# Why was this migrated?

Tags: discussion

[How do expert writers avoid using "I" when they have to refer to themselves in their article?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12472/how-do-expert-writers-avoid-using-i-when-they-have-to-refer-to-themselves-in-t)

This active question has 10 answers (of which one has 24 upvotes!) and an accepted answer already. Not that I object, but why was it migrated to Writers? It seems like English was doing fine with it.

Answer (score 2):

That a question attracts a lot of answers on a site doesn't mean that it's on-topic there.  Sometimes users are enthusiastic. :-)

The moderators of ELU asked about migrating to us (I guess it was going to be closed there) and we accepted.  I hadn't noticed the large number of answers at the time.  If any are not suitable answers *by this site's standards*, please flag them.

It is a frequent source of frustration to me that posts migrate with their votes intact; it can really distort things on the receiving site.  [This request on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87031/162102) was declined some time back, but maybe if enough (more) people lobby for it, it might help?

Comment: Clearing votes probably does not have much more chance than supporting tables. (While tables are not often useful on SO, Writers, or perhaps most other SE sites, the current workarounds are images—which have their own issues, including accessibility—and preformatted text.) It probably also has a better chance than allowing use of the `id` attribute to support more precisely targeted urls. (I guess I am in a whining mood at the moment.)

Answer (score 1):

We EL&U mods thought you Writers community might like it.

The OP asked this [same question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5078/why-has-my-notable-question-migrated-to-the-writers) on EL&U Meta, and the migrating mod answered it there. I thought I would mention it to you.

Comment: Your antecedent for "we" and "our" (the moderators at ELU involved in the migration for "we"; the ELU community for "our") could be made clearer. (I also assume "you" refers to the Writers community, i.e., "you folks", not specifically Lauren Ipsum.)

Comment: @Paul Don't you know who I am? Oh...oh...I suppose you don't.

Comment: I thought you were probably a mod at EL&U based on previous statements (and confirmed by searching the user list at EL&U), but with only the local context the pronouns seemed a little awkward. Moderators at EL&U should be held to higher standards of clarity in communicating in English.☺